# Activity Indicator on Android App using mvvmcross

Tags: android, progress-bar, mvvmcross, activity-indicator

I'm developing an Android App using MVVMCross. I'm using the progressbar tag on AXML, and it stop the animation whenever the app has a background activity. I guess its because I'm using in a wrong way the syncronous tasks but I don't find the way to solve it.

The ProgressBar tag that I'm using is:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="#88000000"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  local:MvxBind="Visibility Visibility(IsLoading)"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
  <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/element_margin_large"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/element_margin_large" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried changing `IsLoading` to `true` , to keep it visible all time, and the animation stops everytime the app does any back process.

EDIT: The code I tried on viewmodel is something like this:

```
private MvxCommand _xxxCommand;
        public ICommand XxxCommand
        {
            get
            {
                _xxxCommand = _xxxCommand ?? new MvxCommand(XxxCmd);
                return _xxxCommand;
            }
        }

public async void XxxCmd()
        {
            IsLoading = true;
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {          
            ShowViewModel<XxxViewModel>();
            });
            IsLoading = false;
        }
```

But it keeps freezing while `ShowViewModel` is executed. In the next view I have some bindings and calls to an external `API`, but all of them are `async` and `awaited`

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the UI itself, but as you say yourself, you are blocking the UI thread with the synchronous code you are executing.

You need to either use ThreadPool or Task to encapsulate those things you do and run them in the background rather than eating up the UI thread's time.

The specific implementation will depend on your code, which you have not provided in your opening post.

Comment: Debbuging the app I found that i when the program execute the 'ShowViewModel<...>();' when the animation stops. I tried encapsulating it with 'await Task.Run(() =>{(...)};' but still freezing.

Comment: What do you doing in Init or Start or Constructor of the ViewModel you are showing?

Comment: In the constructor, I initialize two interfaces of two services and I call 2 async methods.

Comment: I also tried in a testViewModel, with an empty constructor, encapsulating the `ShowViewModel` method with `await Task.Run` , and with the `ProgressBar` with `visibility = true`, the animation keeps freezing for a little time before starting the animation of changing of view